# Как добавить изображение на гугл карту?

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить свое изображение на гугл карту? Если добавлять его как маркер, то он реагирует на нажатие, а надо просто нарисовать png кружок..

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй [ответ отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226453/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable).

Там в коде ответа есть метод `onMarkerClick()`.

Попробуй проверять, если клик по маркеру не должен происходить, обработай в этом методе (думаю, нужно всего лишь `return false;` если нажат маркер-картинка).

Comment: Спасибо, а другого способа нету? У меня просто маркеры с кластерами сделаны, а картинку добавляю как обычный маркер(иначе будет добавляться в кластер), и соответственно  при нажатии на нее слушатель onMarkerClick(Marker marker) не срабатывает, а срабатывает слушатель кластеров mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener... Условие return true; не сделать к маркеру картинки, и она реагирует на нажатие..

Comment: @Alex455 про "маркер с кластерами" не понял. А что, если добавлять картинку через "маркер с кластерами", но добавлять ещё при этом тэг для маркера? а в кликлистенере проверять маркер по тегу (картинка или нет)?

Comment: Если рядом в кластерах добавить более 4-х картинок, то они спрячутся в кластер.. В общем пока думаю..

Comment: @Alex455 а если ты сделаешь кастомный кластер, который будет игнорировать маркеры с тегом картинки на карте?